# Blocked due to unauthorised request (401) error thrown by Google Indexing and Lighthouse PageSpeed Test

Tags: web-scraping, google-search-console, http-status-code-401, lighthouse, googlebot

I have a [website](https://bicheng.me) and it was deployed on Vercel. When I try to index the page using Google Search Console, it throws error: *Blocked due to unauthorised request (401)*

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McE6O.png)

I then visited their help article to find more information about the error.

> Blocked due to unauthorized request (401)
> The page was blocked to Googlebot by a request for authorization (401 response). If you do want Googlebot to be able to index this page, either remove authorization requirements for this page, or else allow Googlebot to access your pages by verifying its identity. You can verify this error by visiting the page in incognito mode.

After verifying this error by visiting the page in incognito mode as suggested in the article. I am  totally able to access my page using incognito mode.

[Page in Incognito Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joWl2.png)

In additional, I am also not able to get my page run lighthouse page speed test. The error code is same *401*. Complete error code: *Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page that you requested. Make sure that you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to all requests. (Status code: 401)*

Kindly suggest what could I do to fix this. Thank you!

Comment: You may have something on your server, firewall or CDN that detects Googlebot and Google tools (maybe IP address) and returns the 401 status.

Comment: @bc2ajia I am facing the same problem using NextJs & Vercel as the server.
I ran the diagnostics for your website now and i can see you have the report.
May i ask how you fixed it? It would be great if you answered your own post.

Waiting for your reply

Comment: Same issue here. Vercel + Next.js. 401 error from lighthouse and no problem whatsoever accessing from icognito or curl. After examining web requests in logs it is clear that authentication middleware has something to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to turn of Vercel Authentication in your vercel dashboard

[image]